# Using a 'Parent' repo to track all of my group's projects as submodules with Git

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I've been working on migrating my workplace to work exclusively with git for version control but one of the stipulations put forth by my team lead was that he (and anyone else interested) would have a simple way to just clone the entirety of our team's projects (we are not programmers, but system engineers so we're not talking huge codebases, but an assorted collection of utilities and scripts written in MATLAB, Python and the likes).

My suggestion is to take advantage of git's submodule system in order to do the tracking - while each individual will manage their own repo however they please, they will provide either my team lead or another appointed moderator a specific commit which is their 'stable' and most up to date version.
We in turn will be doing the bookkeeping in a specially made 'Parent' repository which will simply have some documentation for the team and the rest will be folders that are submodules of all the projects, with each submodule pointing to that project's 'stable' commit provided by the individual responsible for that project.

While this is not exactly 'clean' git etiquette to my best knowledge, it's the mode of operations which as far as I know best suites our needs of being hands on with bookkeeping and having all the projects accessible in one place.

I do however have some questions to which I am not sure I have a definitive answer:

1. Is having 2 submodules pointing to 2 different commits of the same repository in one parent repository possible (e.g. having different 'release' versions of the same project, like a submodule pointing to 'Project v1.0' and one pointing to 'Project v1.2')?
2. Is it possible to clone the parent repository without pulling all the contents of the child repositories (this is not a deal breaker, but I would like to know this before presenting to the team)
3. Is it possible to track the head of a certain branch (i.e. the latest commit of that branch)
4. This is not specifically planned to be a part of this repo, but is git a solid option for tracking compiled versions of projects? Like, does having a repository of all the compiled utilities made by our team make sense or is it just better to leave them all in a server folder as we do now?